# Is it possible to define a function that takes a different form based on the sign of the parameter in Theano

Tags: python, theano

I need to define the following function. Is it possible to do in Theano?
[image]

**UPDATE:**

To clarify I'm asking about defining a theano symbolic variable that can take the above form. I understand that I can define 2 separate variables and use either of them based on the value of R. My questions here is it possible to define a single variable that takes the above form. The reason is that I need to take gradients of this variable as well as use it in other variables and it would drastically simplify my solution if I can define this withing a single symbolic variable.

**UPDATE 2:**

Proposed solution with *lambda* doesn't work. This doesn't generate a symbolic variable that can later be used with Theano:

```
r = T.dscalar('r')
dd = lambda r: r + 1 if r > 0 else r - 1
```

Comment: I'm sure it is. Why don't you try and then come back when you hit a specific problem that you need help with.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I already searched the docs and I couldn't find the solution

Comment: @MorganThrapp the reason I'm asking this is exactly because I hit a specific problem within a much larger scope. The reason for downvote is not clear.

Comment: Then you need to add that to your question. Right now your question reads "Here's my problem, write the code for me". It seems like you'd benefit from re-reading [help] and [faq] and maybe even [mcve].

Comment: I mean, right now the answer to the question in your title is yes. `x = lambda y: return y + 1 if y>0 else return y - 1`. I don't know what your actual issue is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and will let you know if this worked.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I edited my question, hope it is not 'write the code for me' anymore. Please consider removing downvote.

Comment: If you can get the sign into a symbol/variable, e.g. `s= (v> 0)` [not sure how to do this in Theano), then you could do something like `topEquation * s + bottomEquation * (s ^ 1)` - this gives you a "linear" equation, where one of the equations will be "dropped" because it's multiplied by 0. I don't know enough Theano to suggest an actual solution; this is just a thought.

Comment: @dwanderson brilliant! this works and I can take gradients. Please post an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing specifics about Theano, I remember that one way to turn an `if-else`  statement into a linear equation is to make your `if` check into a variable itself, setting it as `0` or `1`. Then, you can do something like:

```
sign = (R_t > 0) ## this is the part I don't know how exactly to do
(topEquation * sign) + (bottomEquation * (sign ^ 1))
```

This has the nice property that if `sign` is `1` (or `True`), the `bottomEquation` will drop out, being multiplied by `1 ^ 1` or just `0`. Similarly, `topEquation` drops out if `sign` is `0`/`False`.

One note, though maybe Theano can help with this - it will still **evaluate** both equations, so this could present an efficiency concern (for every single input, it's running both equations, and then ignoring one of them).